# In Andengine making physics body sporting multi-resolution

Tags: android, box2d, andengine, scaling, game-physics

I am facing  a strange kind of problem while making a physics body in andengineBox2d. I have made all the game using 800x480 resolution and scaling all the graphics using a function to support all resolutions. So when I run the game in 320x480 (Galaxy Ace), all the sprites and graphics are looking perfect (scaled) according the resolution but the circular body which I made in 800x480 resolution is still in the same size. I don't know what's wrong with it...
Please help... I am stuck here.

Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't the scaling be automatic? What function are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your interest JohnEye.. i had some problem with resolution policy,now its working

Comment: can you please post the comments. Bodies are not scaled properly